# Two internet connections on one computer

Tags: internet, connection, gaming, browsing

It is possibile to use one internet connection (ISDN) for browser and another one (mobile LTE from usb modem) for game?

EDIT:// I am really sorry about not including specs. My system is windows 7 x64 with service pack1. I am working on PC. 
To be more particular- I want to download some file (in example by browser) with ONLY ISDN connection, but to play game with my lte modem in the SAME TIME. So I want to attach one connection to one program and the second one to game. It is possible? I think it is deafult gateway attaching, but I could be wrong...

Comment: If you want real answers please [edit] your question to include your operating system.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to be a little more specific. What OS, is it a laptop or desktop, are you using Wifi or Wired. OS and hardware setup would be very helpful in getting someone to answer your question, which I assume is really, how to have both hooked up at once, and have them used independently.

In short, you can connect your computer to your ISDN connection then browse the web. When you're done browsing, disconnect your ISDN and connect your LTE connection, then game until you pass out.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it with linux based router 
for example in CENTOS you can make route table and redirect browser dsts from port 80/443 to one conection and ather traffics to second

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you could try bridging the connections or use: `Connectify Dispatch Pro`. The software can be tried for free if I'm sure and it let's you combine internet connections. Meaning, if you have 1 adapter that has 20 mbps and one with 30 mbps, connectify will make it into a 50 mbps adapter. I hope this is what you want, I don't really think you can assign an adapter to your webbrowser or a game, I might be wrong though :)!